# I don't know why im getting this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, html

i can't get why this code isn't right. everything seems good to me, but i keep getting the same error.

here's my html:

```
        <form class="numeros" >
        <div class="entradas" >
            <input type="number" vaid = "numero1" placeholder="#1">
            <input type="number" id = "numero2" placeholder="#2">
            <input type="number" id = "numero3" placeholder="#3">
            <input type="number" id = "numero4" placeholder="#4">
        </div>
        <input type="button" onclick="ejecutar()" id ="enviar" value="Enviar">
        <textarea readonly name="" id="resultado" placeholder="Resultados"></textarea>
    </form>
```

and here's my js code.

```
document.getElementById(numero1).value = 0;
document.getElementById(numero2).value = 0;
document.getElementById(numero3).value = 0;
document.getElementById(numero4).value = 0;
```

Comment: `getElementById` takes a string parameter.

Comment: is there any way to take a number as  a parameter? or should i put a text input and parse it?

Comment: as a parameter of what?

Comment: i missunderstood your comment, now i get it. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to note that ElementById needs a string. When you declared the id of the element, it had quote marks. The same goes for when you reference it.

So just change everything that looks like this...

```
document.getElementById(numero4).value = 0;
```

...to this...

```
document.getElementById('numero4').value = 0;
```

...and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 1):

what is see is a typo in this one

```
 <input type="number" vaid = "numero1" placeholder="#1">
```

should be **id** instead of **vaid**

```
 <input type="number" id = "numero1" placeholder="#1">
```

also, the element id should be a string **"numero1"** instead of **numero1**

```
document.getElementById("numero1").value = 0;
```